# Meterpreter: How to invoke commands in a loop for each new connection

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I want to execute commands like `screenshot` on a regular interval (e.g. each 5min) for each incoming connection to Meterpreter using the `reverse_tcp` payload until the connection gets closed by the Windows clients.

Is there any straightforward way to realize dynamic handling of incoming connections?

Comment: I am not sure if the meterpreter is being notified by DBUS, but if yes you can use DBUS to execute the command or write your own daemon to sit in the background and check periodically check and execute the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Metasploit scripting](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-scripting/) supports [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/), so you could build your workflow around something like...

```
<ruby>
while true
  run_single("screenshot")  
  run_single("sleep 300s") 
end
</ruby>
```